# How to Attach and Detch the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2005-express

HI guys I have  2005 database I attached to 2005 instance how to convert it to 2012 SQL 
after I do attach show me this. so what is the next step can you provide some guidelines please. thank you in advanced 
 [image]

Comment: Is there something wrong with the 2012 docs? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Comment: No but the database has been created with 2005 SQL beta and won't work on 2012 so guys here told me to attach it in 2005 instance than 2008 than 2012 but I don't know the steps can you provide some help please :)

Comment: Same documentation page has an "other versions" drop down, that brings up instructions for 2005, 2008. From there it's just a matter of installing all those database servers somewhere.

Comment: I made attach to the database with 2005 instance what is the next ?

Comment: Detach from 2005, attach to 2008. Detach from 2008, attach to 2012. Each time it attaches, it should upgrade to that version.

Comment: bro the problem in detaching I don't know how to do detach is there any pictures or video can help me to do this step

Comment: problem has been solved thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved by attaching with 2005 SQL then Detaching ,attaching with 2008 SQL and so on attach and detach until u reach the 2012 instance with every time should be upgraded